# D3 Selecting an element inside an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create some graphs in D3. So far love it, but I'm getting a bit stuck. 
I want to create one area to hold the data points and another to hold the axis and labels. 
I think I will go even more fine grained than that to make updating the graph more efficient. But the issue I am having is that I can't seem to select sub elements within the SVG.

Here is what I have:

```
var graph = d3.select('#Graph svg')
if (graph[0][0] == null){
    graph = d3.select('#Graph')
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width",width)
        .attr("height",height)
        .attr("class","chart");
}

graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("id","data")
```

Now I have not found a way to select that data container. I have tried

```
d3.select("#Graph svg data")
```

But no luck. Any Ideas?

Comment: If you want to select something with an `id` of `data`, you should be selecting `#Graph svg #data`, right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's try this code.

```
d3.select("#Graph svg").selectAll("g")
```

"g" means to select all node "g" under svg node.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your data container with `append()`, you can save it as a selection to a variable.

```
var dataContainer = graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("id","data");
```

If done in this way, you won't ever need to make the d3 selection again (in a similar way you have done with `var graph` on the 1st line of the code in your question), because a reference to this selection is already stored in your var `dataContainer`.